# Export running Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I was just hit by a ransomware that encripted most of my data. It is one of the ransomware for which decryption is currently unknown and I don't have a backup copy.

The point is that I was running a Java application using Eclipse that takes several computing days. The ransomware encripted both the .java files and the .class files in "src" and "bin" folders, but the Java application is still running fine, so it seems that the Java Virtual Machine might have a local copy of the binary files. Do you know if there is some way to get the .class files from the running JVM? Then, I would decompile it to retrieve my original source files.

Thank you very much in advance and best regards!

**Edit**: Thank you very much to everybody. I retrieved the .class files and could decompile then into very reasonable .java files.

@valiano's solution worked. Note that jvminspector assumes that your classes are not in the default package, otherwise line 67 of DumpAgent.java produces an exception (a minor change in the code is needed to recover when lastIndexOf returning -1).

@StephaneM's solution worked sometimes, but in some cases running classdumper.jar makes Eclipse kill the process because of an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

I also found two more solutions:

a) a similar project called dumpclass (https://github.com/hengyunabc/dumpclass)

b) sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.jcore.ClassDump class. Example of use: java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\lib\sa-jdi.jar" -Dsun.jvm.hotspot.tools.jcore.filter=sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.jcore.PackageNameFilter -Dsun.jvm.hotspot.tools.jcore.PackageNameFilter.pkgList= sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.jcore.ClassDump

Comment: The JVM loads classes in to memory as required. As far as I know there is no way to save them.

Comment: Have you tried that: https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/retrieving-class-files-from-a-running-app ?

Comment: “decompile it to retrieve my original source files”… a decompiler will not give you back your original source files. It will produce something that, in the best case, could get recompiled to an equivalent code. But be prepared for something not even close to that, requiring even more effort on clean up than rewriting the code from scratch.

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful:
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/17244/21194
BTW, are you running Oracle's HotSpot JVM? On which operating system?